# share screen chrome not showing all applications

Tags: google-chrome, 21.04

I'm using ubuntu21.04

I have a problem with sharing screen. for example in google chrome when I want to share one application, some of them are not on the list. and I should share the whole screen to share these applications. for example, I can share a terminal or some other apps. but I cannot share Telegram-desktop or OpenBoard.
I test sharing desktop in discord and it has the same problem.
I think Ubuntu cannot detect these apps as sharable apps.

Answer (score 0):

I was resolved by going to `chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer` and changing the value from `Default` to `Enabled`.

then

Search for the **file.conf** in **/etc/gdm3/** in my case, Ubuntu 22.04, it's **custom.conf**

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

uncomment the line

`#WaylandEnable=false` to be `WaylandEnable=false`

then `reboot`

"*uncommenting that line will use the Xorg display manager instead of Wayland* "

Comment: Please do not copy and paste identical answers to different questions on AU. The system has detected this *exact* answer given to 3 slightly different questions.